# Nested object array Javascript regarding oops return method

Tags: javascript, oop, nested

You are given an object which has details of a particular class. Complete the function so that it returns the details of the student at i th index in the form of an array.

Input Format: Given the index (i) of the student whose details should be printed.

Output Format: An array containing name and roll no of the student.

Sample Input:

```
1
```

Sample Output

```
Bhavya
2
```

My output is somewhat wierd, can anyone help me out? how to resolve this?

```
 function studentDetails(i) { 
        var classDetails = {
            classTeacher: 'Anjani',
            students: [{name: "Anjali", roll: "1"}, {name: "Bhavya", roll: "2"}, {name: "Neha", roll: "3"}]
        };
      
       return classDetails.students[i].name;
        
      }
    
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
    
    let remainder = '';
    process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
        let t = parseInt(chunk);
        let ans = studentDetails(t);
        for(var i=0; i<ans.length; i++)
        {
            process.stdout.write(ans[i]+'\n');
        }
        process.exit();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = []
arr.push(classDetails.students[i].name);
arr.push(classDetails.students[i].roll);
return arr;
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

`studentDetails()` needs to return the entire object, not just the name.

Then there's no need for a loop, just print its `name` and `roll`.

```js
function studentDetails(i) {
  var classDetails = {
    classTeacher: 'Anjani',
    students: [{
      name: "Anjali",
      roll: "1"
    }, {
      name: "Bhavya",
      roll: "2"
    }, {
      name: "Neha",
      roll: "3"
    }]
  };

  return classDetails.students[i];

}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  let t = parseInt(chunk);
  let ans = studentDetails(t);
  process.stdout.write(ans.name + '\n');
  process.stdout.write(ans.roll + '\n');
  process.exit();
});
```